# Почему перестают работать клики мыши и alt+tab ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, мышь, click

Случается такое: работаю себе, работаю и бац! Перестают работать клики мыши. Мышь двигается по экрану, а на нажатие интерфейс не реагриует. Все окна (которые видно ) работают нормально, не виснут, но работать я могу только с последним активным окном или вызвать консоль, а Alt+Tab'ом вернуться к прошлому окну не смогу, при нажатии Alt+Tab ничего не происходит. Все что остается писать конманды в консоль или reboot. Это на разных Ubuntu, Lubuntu  и т.д. случается. Кто сталкивался ?

Comment: А батарейки в мыше пробовал менять?)

Comment: Из-за батареек Альт+таб не рабоатет?